# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in BooksController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My Application name is LibraryWebApplication when I accessing my new.erb file using **/books/new** its giving the form then I filled the form with title,price,description then I clicked the button create its is going to following url **/books/create** but its is not storing data into data base its showing the following error 
        ctiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in BooksController#create
        ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
        I am new to rails could not able to find the solution for this
        Extracted source (around line #13):

```
      def create
          @book = Book.new(params[:book])-----this is line no:13
          if @book.save
                redirect_to :action => 'list'
          else
```

Rails.root: D:/RailsAppsExamples/LibrarayWebApplication

stacktrace is

```
    Started POST "/books/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 14:58:25 +0530
    Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"TfBODzvGFAE6RkCmfPAAx/EhkSJkCeYUemr129dKYjc=", "book"=>{"title"=>"Advanced Physics", "price"=>"523", "subject_id"=>"2", "description"=>"mathsbk"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
      app/controllers/books_controller.rb:13:in `create'


      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (15.6ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (15.6ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (62.5ms)
    [2014-03-18 15:03:14] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


    Started POST "/books/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 15:04:48 +0530
    Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"TfBODzvGFAE6RkCmfPAAx/EhkSJkCeYUemr129dKYjc=", "book"=>{"title"=>"Advanced Physics", "price"=>"523", "subject_id"=>"2", "description"=>"mathsbk"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
      app/controllers/books_controller.rb:13:in `create'


      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (31.2ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (78.1ms)
```

I have two models

book.rb

```
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :subject
        validates_presence_of :title
      validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
    end
```

subject.rb

```
    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :books
    end
    my controller is
    books_controller.rb
    class BookController < ApplicationController
       def list
          @books = Book.find(:all)
       end
       def show
          @book = Book.find(params[:id])
       end
       def new
          @book = Book.new
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       end
       def create
          @book = Book.new(params[:book])
          if @book.save
                redirect_to :action => 'list'
          else
                @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
                render :action => 'new'
          end
       end
```

my routes.rb is

```
    LibrarayWebApplication::Application.routes.draw do
        get 'books/new'
        post 'books/create'
      get 'books/list'
       get 'books/show'
      get 'books/edit'
     get 'books/show_subjects'
    end
```

new.erb file is

```
    <h1>Add new book</h1>
    <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
    <p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
    <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
    <p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
    <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %></p>
    <p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
    <%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></p>
    <p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
    <%= text_area 'book', 'description' %></p>
    <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

migration files are

20140318084539_books.rb

```
    class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
         create_table :books do |t|
      t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
      t.column :price, :float
      t.column :subject_id, :integer
      t.column :description, :text
      t.column :created_at, :timestamp
         end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :books
      end
    end
```

20140318084609_subjects.rb

```
    class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
          create_table :subjects do |t|
           t.column :name, :string
        end
        Subject.create :name => "Physics"
        Subject.create :name => "Mathematics"
        Subject.create :name => "Chemistry"
        Subject.create :name => "Psychology"
        Subject.create :name => "Geography"
      end

      def self.down
          drop_table :subjects
      end
    end
```

the above code is created tables in the the database and is it compulsory to write the test and production in database.yml..can we write only development only...

I am using Rails4.0.3 with eclipse plugin

Comment: This question comes up a lot on SO. Checkout the links on the right, they will point you to the right direction (hint: strong parameters).

Comment: what do you mean by mass assignment

Comment: In Strong parameter is method should relate to controller's method name?

Comment: From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters): With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.

Comment: I am unable to write the strong parameters its showing the error I am new to ruby and rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really recommend you to read the railsguides, because there are some serious problems with your code. When I stick to your question, the answer is you have to use strong parameters. What that means? Well, strong parameters determine what attributes can be whitelisted.

Before Rails 4 attributes where whitelisted in the model through attr_accessible. Rails 4 uses strong parameters, which belong to the controller.

I will give a basic example:

```
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    <rest of code>
  end

private
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :content)
  end
```

Now the attributes title and content are no longer forbidden, because you explicitly permit them using strong parameters.

I guess I should write an article specific for strong parameters, because there seems to be quite some confusion about them. Here you can see an example controller with strong parameters in place: http://rails4guides.com/articles/clean-code-rails-style-guide

Comment: ok I will accept. params.require(:book).permit(:title, :content) in this title and content are the parameters of the form?

Comment: Yes, it is just an example. In this case only the title and the content of a book are accessible.